# Make the program pause by button or mouse click in python package matplotlib

Tags: python, click, pause

Through the program interface button or mouse click to make the program pause, click the button or mouse again to allow the program to continue from the place where it was last stopped, the focus is to pause how to achieve.The time from the last pause again  is uncertain.My codes are following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class ab():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
a=ab(2,4)
b=ab(2,6)
c=ab(2,8)
d=ab(6,10)
f=ab(6,13)
e=ab(6,15)
task=[]
task.append(a)
task.append(b)
task.append(c)
task.append(d)
task.append(e)
task.append(f)
for i in task:
    while i.x<=30:
        print(i.x)
        plt.plot(i.x,i.y,'o')
        plt.pause(0.1)
        i.x=i.x+2
        i.y=i.y+2

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [matplotlib's animation module](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) with [matplotlib's event connections](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html). The code below should do more or less what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# I'm replacing your class with two lists for simplicity
x = [2,2,2,6,6,6]
y = [4,6,8,10,13,15]

# Set up the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
point, = ax.plot(x[0],y[0],'o')

# Make sure all your points will be shown on the axes
ax.set_xlim(0,15)
ax.set_ylim(0,15)

# This function will be used to modify the position of your point
def update(i):
    point.set_xdata(x[i])
    point.set_ydata(y[i])
    return point

# This function will toggle pause on mouse click events
def on_click(event):
    if anim.running:
        anim.event_source.stop()
    else:
        anim.event_source.start()
    anim.running ^= True

npoints = len(x)

# This creates the animation
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, npoints, interval=100)
anim.running=True

# Here we tell matplotlib to call on_click if the mouse is pressed
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

# Finally, show the figure
plt.show()
```